# Investigate docker error standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory

Tags: docker

While I am trying to minimize some docker image I started using

```
FROM scratch
```

but when I do so I get

```
docker run --rm my/image:latest
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory
```

however when I switch back to

```
FROM alpine:latest
```

execution works as desired. So I doubt I am suffering linefeed issues or missing dependencies in my go application. Instead I believe this is due to the system expecting /bin/sh to be available. But rather than poking in the dark and assuming problems...

What would be a procedure to find out what is missing? How can I find out exactly what file or directory docker could not find?

Comment: Meanwhile I found the issue via poking and stumbling over something - it had cost me quite some time already. Hence I'd still like to have an alternative to 'luck' for future resolution...

Answer (score 0):

If you're image is `FROM scratch`, you're missing *everything*.  That base image contains absolutely nothing at all – no shell, no shared libraries, no directories.  If you're not sure how you'd work in that environment, starting from an Alpine or Ubuntu base image will be much easier.

Practically, the only times using `FROM scratch` makes sense are if you're building your own base image from a distribution tar file (`alpine` and `ubuntu` have their own Dockerfiles that start `FROM scratch`) or if you're working in a compiled language and have built a static binary (you see this sometimes for Go applications, it would also be possible in C++ or Rust, but not any JVM or interpreted language).